# cURL cookiejar line commented out with #HttpOnly_?

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to login to a PunBB forum from a different page on the same domain using cURL.

When logging in, cURL gets executed and its initial response is the 'successful login' page of the forum. However no cookie got set thus when clicking any link in that forum, and I'm logged out.

After a bit of investigating my cookiejar file mentions the cookie needed to login. If I create this cookie and its value manually inb my browser, I am successfully logged in and all is well. So the cookie value stored is correct.

The line containing my cookie name/value in the cookiejar is however commented out.

first question: Why?
second: How to prevent that behavior?

Here's my cookiejar:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

www.example.com FALSE   /   FALSE   0   PHPSESSID   3d7oe6vt3blv3vs3ea94nljcs7
#HttpOnly_www.example.com   FALSE   /   FALSE   1340974408  forum_cookie_e19209 MnwyYWQ4OGViNDI2NjE5MWEwMGZiNGZkNDFmZDY5ZDZhYjM5OTA5NDVjfDEzNDA5NzQ0MDh8OTU0NTExOGZhNWNlNGY5OGMzZDk3MmE0NDlmMWRjNzM3ZjI1NzMxOA%3D%3D
```

And here's my curl call:

```
function forumLogin() {
    $loginFields = array('req_username' => $_REQUEST['username']
                        ,'req_password' => $_REQUEST['password']
                        ,'form_sent' => "1"
                    ); //and so on
    $login = getUrl('http://www.example.com/manager/forum/login.php', 'post', $loginFields);
   return $login;
}

function getUrl($url, $method='', $vars='') 
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  if ($method == 'post') {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
  }
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $buffer;
}

// successful login so reset fail count and update key values
if(isset($_SESSION['mgrValidated'])) {
    $sql = "update $dbase.`".$table_prefix."user_attributes` SET failedlogincount=0, logincount=logincount+1, lastlogin=thislogin, thislogin=".time().", sessionid='$currentsessionid' where internalKey=$internalKey";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql);
    var_dump( forumLogin() );
}
exit;
```

Answer (score 13):

The #Httponly_ prefix on a line is not a comment. It is a magic string to tell the browser/client that the cookie in question is a [httponly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) one. curl will understand that and deal with it accordingly.

I don't understand the part about clicking on things as I don't see how that is related or relevant to your curl-using program.

Comment: Ah Okay! Thanks Daniel. Seems like I totally misinterpreted the meaning of the hash.

Your comment about not understanding the clicking part. Well, eventhough the cookie gets written to correctly in the cookiejar, it is not set as a regular cookie in the browser. So, the initial response page tells me i'm logged correctly but since the cookie isnt there, i'm really not which becomes painfully obvious when i click any link in the forum (it will tell me im not logged in).

Any thoughts on that one?

Comment: Yes, curl is the client and gets and uses the cookies, it doesn't mean that it sends it to the browser or even that you _can_ send it to the browser who's only watching the results of the curl program.

Comment: I see.
Allright. So i've written a little ditty to grab the correct cookie and have php set it :) Life is good.

Thanks for your help Daniel!

Comment: Hi @Amelia do you mind sharing the little ditty you did  to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Does `wget` also understand the `#Http_only` prefix?